# I am having a problem while creating a token in NodeJS. Is there any solution please?

Tags: node.js, jwt, postman, token, express-jwt

I want to generate token in nodejs where i can authenticate the user.

```
const expressjwt = require('express-jwt');

function authJwt() {
  const secret = process.env.secret;
  return expressjwt({ secret, algorithms: ['HS256'] });
}

module.exports = authJwt;
```

server.js file:

```
const authJwt = require('./helpers/jwt');
app.use(authJwt);
```

I have tried to call authJwt() as well but its not working. Is there any solution or am i doing anything wrong? I am getting this error "TypeError: expressjwt is not a function".

Comment: `const { expressjwt } = require('express-jwt');`